# Is iptables and vpn tunneling enough?

Tags: encryption, exploit, openssl, openvpn, iptables

What is the best approach to secure connection between two devices over the internet (public IP)?

if there is a firewall on my public IP address deny access all incoming connection, can the hacker get access to my server from the internet, or bypass my firewall by any magic exploit or secret technique?

Comment: It sounds like you're literally asking "halp how do I network security" which is an _incredibly_ broad question. There is no one best approach for securing a point-to-point connection over a network. And I can't understand your last sentence at all.

Comment: @forest the last sentence is about: if I setup a Linux server on public IP and using iptables firewall rules to deny all incoming connection to my server, can an attacker get access to my Server?

Answer (score 1):

No one can never ensure you the ultimate safety. The practice you mention though is very good for encrypting an end-to-end connection. Pieces of advice:

1. Create a strong RSA key for the SSL
2. If you feel that iptables is not enough, use an external firewall, which will also be able to work as a vpn server and cover your original server behind it. Apart from the general rules, you can also set up IDS and IPS technologies.
3. Keep your software updated (less magic exploits can occur this way)
4. Watch out from where do you connect over vpn to your server. Try not to use your certificates over many different, not-trusted computers and networks.